# Integrate using given formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I would like to ask for help with exercise I was given on QM. I am suppose to calculate:
$$
\int_{0}^{L}|A|^2|x(L-x)|^2 dx = |A|^2\int_{0}^{L}(x(L-x))^2
$$
That is not a problem of course. I am suppose to use this formula to calculate the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}t^m(1-t)^n dt=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}
$$
Could anyone point my how to approach it. I have never seen such integral before.

Thank you for reeding. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Limits suggest substitution $u=x/L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're suppose to use "this formula", since your first equation is trivial; the only change is that $|A|^2$ is moved outside of the integral.

To calculate the value of
$$I_{m,n}=\int_0^1 t^m(1-t)^n\ dt,$$
we can repeatedly integrate by parts to raise the degree of $t^m$ and lower the degree of $(1-t)^n$. First, note that if $n=0$ then the equation is true, since
$$\int_0^1 t^m\ dt = \frac{1}{m+1} = \frac{m!}{(m+1)!}.$$
Integrating the genreal integral by parts once, we get
$$\int_0^1 t^m(1-t)^n\ dt = \frac{t^{m+1}(1-t)^n}{m+1}\bigg|_0^1 + \frac{n}{m+1}\int_0^1 t^{m+1}(1-t)^{n-1}\ dt.$$
Simplifying, this gives us the relation
$$I_{m,n} = \frac{n}{m+1}I_{m+1,n-1}.$$
Using this relation repeatedly until we hit $n=0$, we get
\begin{align}
I_{m,n} &= \frac{n!}{(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+n)}I_{m+n,0}\\ 
&= \frac{n!}{(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+n)(m+n+1)}\\
&= \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!}.
\end{align}